# create a conditional column based on multiple columns in two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe:
df1 
[image: df1]

and df2

[image: df2]

I need to create column 'Form In' in df1 based on condition from column of df1.Min of TV if the value is equal or less to form_col1, add df2.form to df1.Form In(new Column)

expect result is
[image: Result]

I tried this but no success

```
df1['Form In']=df1.apply(lambda x: df2['Form'] if df1['Min of TV'] <= df2['Form_Col1'] else nan)
```

i got this error:

```
ValueError: ('Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects', 'occurred at index Oper_Dep')
```

How do I create a column based on the condition above?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for join both `Dataframe`s together, then filter by mask (seems is necessary change `<=` to `>=`), remove duplicates by `Name` with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and create `Series` for [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='Name')
s = (df[df['Min of TV'] >= df['Form_Col1']]
          .drop_duplicates('Name', keep='last')
          .set_index('Name')['Form'])
df1['Form in'] = df1['Name'].map(s)
```